# Don't understand why I get: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

I get an syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in this function on the 2nd line:

```
function format_date($unixtime) {
return date(“F”, $unixtime).” “.date(“d”, $unixtime).”, “.date(“Y”, $unixtime);
}
```

I'm following this tutorial http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-wordpress-custom-post-types-to-add-events-to-your-site/

I've followed this to the letter and did nothing more than copy and paste so far.

In the comments you can read that the function above is missing and the author says to include it anyware in the php file. This seems to solve it for everybody except one other person and me.

So maybe the problem is related with the version of PHP or MySQL? Although Netbeans also says there is a syntax error in the code above.

Comment: Whatever you see in the internet, you should not expect it to just work. And welcome, you have been fooled by copy and paste programming. Now back to the manual and learn how to write strings: http://php.net/string

Comment: `date('F d, Y', $unixtime)` nets same results, only needs 1 `date` call and no string concatenation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you copied and pasted from a badly written blog post and you have invalid curly quotes in your code. Change them to single or double-quotes:

```
 return date("F", $unixtime)." ".date("d", $unixtime).", ".date("Y", $unixtime);
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel so stupid now that I didn't notes the quotes looked differant from normal quotes. Thanks everybody for pointing this out! :)

Answer (score 6):

The double quotes your are using are the wrong ones :

```
function format_date($unixtime) {
return date("F", $unixtime)." ".date("d", $unixtime).", ".date("Y", $unixtime);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there is difference between

```
left double quote       &ldquo; “
right double quote      &rdquo; ”
```

and

```
double quotation mark   &#34;   &quot;  "
```

so what you need to use is double quote([php supports](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)) which <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>'</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Your using Wrong quotes. You have curly quotes, use `"` or `'`

```
function format_date($unixtime) {
return date("F", $unixtime)." ".date("d", $unixtime).", ".date("Y", $unixtime);
}
```